# Overloading global new and delete safely

Tags: c++, dynamic, memory-management

While reading Bruce Eckel i came across the following example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void* operator new(size_t sz) 
{
  printf("operator new: %d Bytes\n", sz);
  void* m = malloc(sz);
  if(!m) puts("out of memory");
   return m;
}

void operator delete(void* m) 
{
 puts("operator delete");
 free(m);
}
 class S {
 int i[100];
 public:
 S() { puts("S::S()"); }
 ~S() { puts("S::~S()"); }
 };

int main() {
puts("creating & destroying an int");
int* p = new int(47);
delete p;
puts("creating & destroying an s");
S* s = new S;
delete s;
puts("creating & destroying S[3]");
S* sa = new S[3];
delete []sa;
}
```

I am having doubt with following statement:

1. Notice that `printf( )` and `puts( )` are used rather than iostreams. This is because when an `iostream` object is created (like the global `cin`, `cout`, and `cerr`), it calls `operator new` to allocate memory. With `printf( )`, you don't get into a deadlock because it doesn't call `new` to initialize itself.
   However, when i am running the program after replacing put with `cout` i am getting no such deadlock. Can anyone explain that?
2. `operator new` returns a void pointer, but finally we are getting pointer to a dynamically allocated object. So is it a constructor that returns a pointer to the object (this, though the constructor doesn't have a return type) or its the compiler that does i internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use of `printf()` to avoid a recursive call into `operator new()` is a safety measure - just to be sure it works. How do you know use of `iostream` never ever causes a call to `operator new()` function?
2. You're confusing *new expression* (a language construct) with `operator new()` function. *new expression* indeed returns a typed pointer, but the a call to `operator new()` function is done "under the hood" and `operator new()` function returns `void*`. The compiler generates all necessary code for that.

Comment: would you like to write an example for 1) where is can cause problem .. for 2) for a new expression..first a call to operator new() is done that return void*..and then compiler call c'tor..and finally we get a pointer to allocated+intilized object..thats why i thought this pointer is returned by c,tor

Comment: @user388338: Imagine `<<` into `cout` tries to `new` something - you've got a recursive call. Constructors don't have return values, so a constructor can't return a pointer.

Comment: you mean something like cout<<new int(1)?? but then the same recurssion ll take place if i use printf("format specifier",new int(1));

Comment: @user388338: No, I mean when you do `cout <<` some C++ code is invoked and it calls something from the C++ library and that code in the library could `new` something for its own purposes.

Comment: Re point 1: the standard allows both printf and ostream to use operator new.  As safety measures go, it's only a probable solution, not a guaranteed one.  (In my own code, I check for recursion, and don't print if I'm in a recursive call.)

Answer (score 2):

1) The C++ standard contains a lot of "mays" which are not usually used. This is one of them. The operator<< function **may** use dynamic memory, but it does not have to. Often this is not the case.

So that your example works does not mean it is correct. It just means it works with the implementation you are using. On other implementations it could break.

The "mays" defined by the standard can also go in another direction. For example any STL-Header may include any other standard header, but is not required to do so. This is often the case with the iostream header and the istream and ostream headers. Almost any implementation includes ostream and istream when iostream is used, but technically they don't have to. This means when you use ostream and just include iostream you program might work, but actually it is not correct as far as the standard is concerned.

For both c and c++ it is rather important to know what may silently break, but this is often not very easy.